# Why are high-sampling-rate data acquisition boards so expensive?

Tags: adc, measurement, datalogger, data-acquisition

An example would be the [NI USB-6366](http://www.ni.com/en-us/support/model.usb-6366.html).

My guess is that it's primarily due to the analog-to-digital converter (ADC) since it should be the component responsible for the high rate conversion, even though I don't know what are the specifics that make high-sampling-rate ADCs expensive (an info on that would be appreciated). Nonetheless, there are all the other considerations like: BNC connectors (for electromagnetic isolation), usb and ethernet connectors, memory, software, # of I/O, etc.

So is it equally the result of all these factors or is there one that stands out?

Comment: Low volumes mean a relatively large portion of the prices are R&D costs.

Comment: Design work, verification, software for this, etc.

Comment: @JorenVaes what about the hardware, it does not count?

Comment: Ofcourse, but gennerally it's not that massive a factor. But ofcourse, these types of things don't use low-quality components

Comment: @TurboJ what do you mean by low volumes? production?

Comment: I would not call the example a board.. it's a complete product targeted for a very small niche market. As others have mentioned, a lot of the cost will be to recoup development, but it also has a number of certifications that also did not come cheap. I would also assume that someone also figured out that whatever market they were after, presumably academia, was willing to fork over big bucks.

Comment: @Trevor okay, good precisions.

Comment: That's not high sampling rate at all. Honestly, you can just connect a Cypress FX3 with any GHz ADC can make such a thing, either of which is terribly expensive.

Comment: It's not especially easy to design things that work at 100MHz and have e.g. very low crossover between channels. It looks like it will have multiple osciliscope-like frontends too. It looks like the sort of thing that costs multiple hundreds of thousands of dollars to design (ie a few senior engineers for several months), and sells maybe a few hundred or thousand units.

Comment: Three words: "amortized R&D costs", and five more words: "What the market will bear".

Answer (score 1):

I would not call the example a board.. it's a complete product targeted for a very small niche market.

As others have mentioned, a lot of the cost will be to recoup development, but it also has a number of certifications that also did not come cheap.

I would also assume that someone also figured out that whatever market they were after, presumably academia, was willing to fork over big bucks.

Comment: I'm surprised that hardware itself has the less influence on the price. Would you say there are cheap alternatives, maybe general purpuse, to the example product I gave?

Comment: Hardware has an effect too, but for products like your example, it's a smaller factor. I am sure you can find a lot cheaper data acquisition solutions out there though, esp PC cards.